# how to add expire to a consent in spring-authorization-server?

Tags: spring-authorization-server

when I agreed to an authorization，I never need to re authorize.

I want it will be valid for a period of time（like one month）.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would to be implement a custom `OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService` that stores the consent in Redis with a TTL (time-to-live).

Comment: 1. I record the expiration time of each content as a separate table.
2. periodically run a task to check which consent has expired, and delete the consent when it expires